# What's the most compact way of encoding lists of symbols from a finite set?

Tags: python, list, encoding, binary, sequence

I'm interested in representing a sequence of symbols from a finite set in the least number of bytes.

For example, say you had a text string which only contained the characters a-z. You could encode them as ascii, so 1 byte per symbol (character). However, by doing that you're only using 26 of the possible 256 values per byte.

I've coded a solution which seems to work well, but I'd like to know if anyone knows or can think of a better way.

My method is to treat the sequence as an integer in base n, where n is `the size of the set of symbols + 1`. For example, if your set or symbols, or "alphabet" was `{a, b, c}` (length 3) then we'd use base 4. The symbols are assigned numerical values so `{a => 1, b => 2, c => 3}`. Therefore, the sequence `[b, a, c]` is treated as the number 213 in base 4, so 39 in decimal. This integer can be encoded in binary, and decoded back to its base 4 representation to retrieve the sequence `2, 1, 3 => [b, a, c]`.

My Python implementation of the above: [radixcodec.py](https://bitbucket.org/hal/radix-codec/src/88e87e2397de/src/radixcodec.py)

So my question is, is there a more space efficient method of encoding lists of elements from a finite set than the one I've described?

Comment: So, for 26 symbols, you would use base 32?

Comment: For 26 symbols I'd use base 27. The base used is number of symbols + 1. This is because 0 can't be used as "000" is the same as "0" or "00".

Comment: See Petr's answer. You can use base 26 for 26 symbols.

Comment: My question is: why do you want this? It sounds like either an attempt at [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) or an academic exercise, neither of which I'd want to use in my code.

Comment: '000' isn't the same as '00' or '0'. It only seems that way because you've avoided coding the length of the coded sequence, relying on an Python integer or string to store the result without thinking about their space overheads (and why they need them). For a more space efficient method I'd start by reading up on Arithmetic coding.

Comment: @PetrViktorin My use case is minimise the file size of an on disk index while maintaining quick/cheap access. I'd get better ratios by just lzma-ing the data, but then I couldn't search it without decompressing the whole thing at once. It is premature optimization though. This is targeting mobile phones, so I like to think I've got more of an excuse than if I was targeting a hefty server.

Comment: @ScottGriffiths True, I figured the added radix size was an OK trade off to avoid explicitly storing the length. I'm not worried about the runtime overhead of the Python data structures I used as the data is going into a file as raw binary ultimately, the Python code is just for generating the data ahead of time. I should probably have made that clear. Thanks for the pointer to Arithmetic coding, looks interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use base *n* where *n* is the number of the symbols (e.g. `{a => 0, b => 1, c => 2}`). That method is optimal if each symbol is equally likely to appear. (You'll also have to store the length of the string, of course. By the way, your implementation uses Python strings; those are definitely not the most space-efficient data structure you can find.)

If the frequencies of the symbols vary, and you know them, you can use [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). If you don't know the frequencies, there's [adaptive Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Huffman_coding).

Anyway, the best method will depend on the application.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'm not worried about the Python data structures as I'm just using the code to assemble a file ahead of time, it's just the size of the raw data in the file I'm considering.